# How to know when to send results of POST request using celery and flask

Tags: flask, celery

This is more of a general understanding question than a specific code example I need help with.

Suppose I have a flask app with a component that can take several minutes to run (the rest is quick by comparison). I then have some client-side code which waits for this to finish running, and then displays the result I send to it. I want to use celery on the slow part to free up these resources, but I don't understand how sending the results back should work. Does the client just keep requesting results (say every second), and if result.ready() = True, then I send the result? This seems inefficient, but I'm not sure what the alternative is?

Comment: What you described is called long polling. Alternatively you can use a websocket or server sent event or many other techniques like push notifications.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't know the names of the things I should be looking for.